# Struct not initializing

Tags: c, struct

Trying to initialize four structs but it says undefined.
The program is in c and using gcc as compiler.

Code below:

```
struct Deck_init{
    int card1, card2;
};

// Initialize player decks
//Deck_init player1_hand, player2_hand, player3_hand, player4_hand; // Need this to work
//Deck_init player1_hand {0,0}; // Test line
//Deck_init player1_hand; // Test line
```

Error:

```
identifier "Deck_init" is undefined
```

If needed, here's the code up to that point:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4 // Number of players 
#define NUM_CARDS_IN_DECK 52 // Cards in deck
#define PTHREADM PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
#define PTHREADC PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER


struct Deck_init{
    int card1, card2;
};

// Initialize player decks
Deck_init player1_hand, player2_hand, player3_hand, player4_hand; // Need this to work
//Deck_init player1_hand {0,0}; // Test line
//Deck_init player1_hand; // Test line
```

What I've done:

- Tried initializing one object
- Tried singaling the problem into it's own seperate file and still problems.

Comment: For C, you need to do `struct Deck_init` or `typedef` the `struct` part away.

Comment: Or if you are serious about this being C++, this code does compile as C++.  Perhaps you are confusing the two languages?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to add the C++ tag, mistakenly did that. Thanks for removing it! It's definetly meant to be in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you have to include the `struct` keyword when declaring a variable:

```c
struct Deck_Init player_hand1, player_hand2; // .. etc
```

or, you can use `typedef` to create an alias of `struct Deck_Init` with a different name.  It's common to simply "remove" the `struct` part, but you can `typedef` to any syntactically-valid name you like:

```c
typedef struct Deck_Init{
    int card1, card;
} Deck_Init; // could just as easily be MyCoolNewDeck

...

// now you can omit the struct part
Deck_Init player_hand1; // etc..
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/qE19bvTa1)

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much! I'll put this as solution once it allows me.